# Google APIs - YouTube commentThreads Not working When searchTerms Param Is Used

Tags: google-api, youtube-api

Seems like the Google API isn't working as expected. When using the searchTerms param I get no results (even when there are comments that use the term) but do get results when I remove the param

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?key={{YOUTUBE_API_KEY}}&part=snippet&videoId={{VID}}&searchTerms=hi&textFormat=plainText
```

Is anyone else seeing this issue / where can I go to report this?